# Basic subset properties

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a very basic question about sets and the subset relation, $\subseteq$.

Let two sets be given by $X=\{1,2\}$ and $Y=\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$

Which relations are valid in the above?

1. $X \subseteq Y$
2. $Y \subseteq X$
3. Both
4. Neither

Comment: OK, then provide some context: why are you interested in the question and what have you tried?

Comment: I am doing homework - True, but this is not the assignment. I am comparing $\sigma$ algebras of different sets, and I realized that I am missing a very basic understanding and got confused

Comment: OK. Please edit your question to say something like "I am trying to understand $\sigma$-algebras. I realised I had some problems with my basic understanding of set theory and came up with the following question to test my understanding ...".

Answer (score 2):

Neither. The elements of $X$ are $1$ and $2$, none of them are elements of $Y$. The elements of $Y$ are $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$, none of them are elements of $X$.

If you want an easy intuitive explanation: the elements of $X$ are numbers, the elements of $Y$ are sets. So none of them can be a subset of the other.

Comment: @Mark Regardless of the OP's motives, you provided an elegant solution. We all have have difficulties with basic things from time to time, and seeing intuition is the best way to learn. Thank you.

Comment: @clathratus: unfortunately, the way numbers are represented in set theory is a basic thing that hasn't been taken into account in this answer.